# Is there a way to configure the storageProviderTimeout in Keycloak?

Tags: java, wildfly, keycloak

I have developed an implementation of the [User Storage SPI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi) that calls an API in a legacy system to migrate users. I need to configure my own value for `storageProviderTimeout` as there is a remote chance that it will take longer than the default 3 seconds to get a response. I have already configured the `socket-timeout-millis` to be more than the default 5 seconds before timing out, but this does not help as the `storageProviderTimeout` has a default of 3 seconds. Upon looking at the Keycloak source code, specifically `AbstractStorageManager.java` there is a mention of this value being configurable:

```
    /**
     * Timeouts are used as time boundary for obtaining models from an external storage. Default value is set
     * to 3000 milliseconds and it's configurable.
     */
    private static final Long STORAGE_PROVIDER_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 3000L;
```

The function to read the configured value looks like this:

```
    protected Long getStorageProviderTimeout() {
        if (storageProviderTimeout == null) {
            storageProviderTimeout = Config.scope(configScope).getLong("storageProviderTimeout", STORAGE_PROVIDER_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
        }
        return storageProviderTimeout;
    }
```

When the `UserStorageManager` instance is created (which extends `AbstractUserManager` the constructor instantiates the superclass with this code:

```
    public UserStorageManager(KeycloakSession session) {
        super(session, UserStorageProviderFactory.class, UserStorageProvider.class,
                UserStorageProviderModel::new, "user");
    }
```

where `"user"` is what later gets passed to `Config.scope()` in the `getStorageProviderTimeout()` function.

What I've tried so far is manually adding the tag `<user>` in `standalone-ha.xml` at the same level as the `<theme>` tag, like this:

```
            <user>
                <storageProviderTimeout>10000</storageProviderTimeout>
            </user>
```

but upon booting Keycloak, I get this error:

```
10:55:59,730 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:143)
        at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:403)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@15.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Unknown keycloak-server subsystem tag: user
```

I hope someone can shed some light on this for me as it feels like I'm missing something obvious. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed here https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/how-to-configure-storageprovidertimeout/9171, there are currently no possibilties to configure this property.

There is an open issue to address this problem: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-18856

As a temporarily quick and dirty workaround you can set the value at runtime via reflections in e.g. your custom UserStorageProvier implementation:

```
public class CustomUserStorageProviderFactory implements UserStorageProviderFactory<CustomUserStorageProvider> {

@Override
public void onCreate(KeycloakSession session, RealmModel realm, ComponentModel model) {
    UserProvider userProvider = session.userStorageManager();

    try {
        Field field = userProvider.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("STORAGE_PROVIDER_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Field modifiers = field.getClass().getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiers.setAccessible(true);
        modifiers.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        field.set(userProvider, 5000L);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks. This workaround is the only solution at this point in time so I am going to mark this as the answer. Now that this issue has been raised and prioritized with the Keycloak team we will hopefully see it fixed in the next major version.

Comment: Thanks for this workaround but with which keycloak version did you test it because i'm still getting the 3000 ms exception with v15.1.1

Comment: This kind of reflective access to the private static final field will not work with Java 17 anymore!

Answer (score 3):

In Keycloak/Quarkus (v17.0.0) you can specify parameter *spi-user-storage-provider-timeout* in the **keycloak.conf** file.

Example (10 seconds):
`spi-user-storage-provider-timeout=10000`

Comment: Tks!! Did you find this in the documentation? Link?

Comment: Worked for me in 21.1.2

```$ bin/kc.sh start-dev --spi-user-storage-provider-timeout=10000```